# Match columns in csv and merge

Tags: linux, awk

I have two csv file a.csv and b.csv. The fifth column in a.csv and the third column b.csv have values, for example

```
a.csv
1,2,3,4,5

b.csv
7,6,5,9
```

If the value of fifth column in a and the value of third column in b matches the resulting csv has to

```
result.csv    
1,2,3,4,5,7,6,9
```

How can this be achieved? Kindly help

Comment: Can you provide a more relevant and representative input file? Currently, `paste -d"," a b` would suffice.

Comment: are two files have same number of lines? do you want to check on the same line (number)?

Comment: Hi Kent

I have to check if the value of the fifth column in a.csv and the third column in b should match, if it matches then the values should merge.

Comment: I'm assuming there will be more than one line in each file. Does a.csv line 1 only need to be compared to b.csv line 1, and line 2 to line 2, etc? Or do you need to scan all of the lines in b.csv until you find a match for column 5 in column 3?

Comment: Use `join` instead of awk.

Comment: @Omnipresence you are very much right i need to scan all the lines.If i have to me more specific , for example i have only **one line** in `a.csv` which has `a,b,c,d,g` and i have `b.csv` which has **three lines** and the occurrence of `g` is in the third line which is like `f,h,g`. Now the resulting set has to be `a,b,c,g,f,h`. Hope i am clear

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Can you explain how you would use `join` to get OPs output ?

Comment: @Jidder Not anymore, as OP's latest comment seems to suggest that the number of fields on each line can vary, and I'm really not sure what constraints there are to deal with. But what I'd had in mind was: `join -t, -1 5 -2 3 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.1,2.2,2.4 a.csv b.csv`. Both `a.csv` and `b.csv` must be sorted on the join fields.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the two files have same number of lines, and you are trying to check the same line number from both file. (i.e. check 3rd line from a.csv against 3rd line from b.csv), this would work:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$3;w[NR]=$1 FS $2 FS $4;next}
                    a[FNR]==$5{print $0, w[FNR]}' b a
```

example:

```
kent$  head a b
==> a <==
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,7
1,2,3,4,8

==> b <==
7,6,5,9
7,6,x,9
7,6,8,9

kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$3;w[NR]=$1 FS $2 FS $4;next}a[FNR]==$5{print $0, w[FNR]}' b a
1,2,3,4,5,7,6,9
1,2,3,4,8,7,6,9
```

Note, if this is not what you are looking for, please clarify your requirements and  the answer would be updated (or removed)

Comment: Hi @Kent

No the line numbers do match. If i have to me more specific , for example i have only one line in `a.csv` which has `a,b,c,d,g` and i have b.csv which has three lines and the occurrence of `g` is in the third line which is like f,h,g. Now the resulting set has to be `a,b,c,g,f,h`. Hope i am clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to match any line with a matching $3 and $5

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," 'NR==FNR{x=$3;$3=$4;NF--;a[x]=x","$0;}$5=a[$5]' file2 file1
```

If you only want it for the same line numbers

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," 'NR==FNR{x=$3;$3=$4;NF--;a[x]=NR;b[x]=x","$0}FNR==a[$5]&&$5=b[$5]' file2 file1
```

Comment: While the solution may be good, it is good to explain the logic. Otherwise, as Kent's is already working, what's the point of posting just a one liner with no more info?

Comment: @fedorqui it can't hurt anyone by being here, also Kents doesn't explain logic either ?

Comment: It is not about hurting, don't get me wrong :) It is just about adding knowledge by indicating what do you do and why.